# Having trouble with grid formating

Tags: html, css, grid, css-grid

I'm trying to create an inline grid. I was able to set up the grid columns and such with no issue, but the divs that are supposed to assign each div to a certain area aren't. Most likely a problem with nesting, but not sure where. Also, please note that this is technically inside another grid but the problem persists even outside of the other grid.

```css
    .galleryGrid {
      display: grid;
      height: 900px;
      margin: auto auto;
      padding-top: 150px;
      grid-template-columns: 150px 150px 150px;
      grid-template-rows: 150px 150px 150px 150px 150px 150px;
      grid-row: 3 / span 1;
      grid-column: 1 / span 1;
      grid-column-gap: 25px;
      grid-row-gap: 25px;
      text-align: center;
    }

    (hashtag)black {
      height: 150px;
      width: 150px;
    }

    .alexRowOne .alexColumnOne {
      grid-column: 1 / span 1;
      grid-row: 1 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowOne .alexColumnTwo {
      grid-column: 2 / span 1;
      grid-row: 1 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowOne .alexColumnThree {
      grid-column: 3 / span 1;
      grid-row: 1 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowTwo .alexColumnOne {
      grid-column: 1 / span 1;
      grid-row: 2 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowTwo .alexColumnTwo {
      grid-column: 2 / span 1;
      grid-row: 2 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowTwo .alexColumnThree {
      grid-column: 3 / span 1;
      grid-row: 2 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowThree.alexColumnOne {
      grid-column: 1 / span 1;
      grid-row: 3 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowThree .alexColumnTwo {
      grid-column: 2 / span 1;
      grid-row: 3 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowThree .alexColumnThree {
      grid-column: 3 / span 1;
      grid-row: 3 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowFour .alexColumnOne {
      grid-column: 1 / span 1;
      grid-row: 4 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowFour .alexColumnTwo {
      grid-column: 2 / span 1;
      grid-row: 4 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowFour .alexColumnThree {
      grid-column: 3 / span 1;
      grid-row: 4 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowFive .alexColumnOne {
      grid-column: 1 / span 1;
      grid-row: 5 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowFive .alexColumnTwo {
      grid-column: 2 / span 1;
      grid-row: 5 / span 1;
    }
    
    .alexRowFive .alexColumnThree {
      grid-column: 3 / span 1;
      grid-row: 5 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowSix .alexColumnOne {
      grid-column: 1 / span 1;
      grid-row: 6 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowSix .alexColumnTwo {
      grid-column: 2 / span 1;
      grid-row: 6 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowSix .alexColumnThree {
      grid-column: 3 / span 1;
      grid-row: 6 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowOne {
      grid-row: 1 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowTwo {
      grid-row: 2 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowThree {
      grid-row: 3 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowFour {
      grid-row: 4 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowFive {
      grid-row: 5 / span 1;
    }

    .alexRowSix {
      grid-row: 6 / span 1;
    }
```

```html
<div class="galleryGrid">
 <div class="alexRowOne">
  <div class="alexColumnOne">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnTwo">
   <img src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAOEAAADhCAMAAAAJbSJIAAAAA1BMVEX///+nxBvIAAAASElEQVR4nO3BgQAAAADDoPlTX+AIVQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADwDcaiAAFXD1ujAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnThree">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="alexRowTwo">
  <div class="alexColumnOne">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnTwo">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnThree">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="alexRowThree">
  <div class="alexColumnOne">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnTwo">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-    solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnThree">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="alexRowFour">
  <div class="alexColumnOne">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnTwo">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnThree">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="alexRowFive">
  <div class="alexColumnOne">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnTwo">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnThree">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="alexRowSix">
  <div class="alexColumnOne">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnTwo">
   <img src="http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/2560x1440/2560x1440-black-solid-color-background.jpg" id="black" height="150px" width="150px">
  </div>
  <div class="alexColumnThree">
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I do not understand what you are wanting either.  Sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want tables and rows, essentially.  You have to make each row a grid and then the divs under that is where you put the grid-column-start property.

Change the css to this,

```
.alexRowOne{
  display:grid;
}
```

and then this,

```
 .alexRowOne .alexColumnOne {
          grid-column: 1 / span 1;
          grid-row: 1 / span 1;
        }
```